# constexpr Optional в С++17 не компилируется

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, constexpr, optional

```
template <typename T>
struct Optional {
    constexpr Optional() : has_value_{false} { }
    constexpr auto has_value() const -> bool { return has_value_; }

    union {
        T value;
    };
    
    bool has_value_;
};

static_assert(not Optional<int>{}.has_value());
```

Почему код не компилируется в C++17, но компилируется в C++20?

> error: non-constant condition for static assertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc ругается более понятно:

```
<source>:13:15: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
   13 | static_assert(not Optional<int>{}.has_value());
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:13:15: error: 'constexpr Optional<T>::Optional() [with T = int]' called in a constant expression
<source>:3:15: note: 'constexpr Optional<T>::Optional() [with T = int]' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
    3 |     constexpr Optional() : has_value_{false} { }
      |               ^~~~~~~~
<source>:3:15: error: 'constexpr' constructor for union 'Optional<int>::<unnamed union>' must initialize exactly one non-static data member
Compiler returned: 1
```

Т.е. проблема в том, что компилятор не смог вывести constexpr конструктор для union-а.
Проблема решается явным указанием инициализирующего значения по умолчанию:

```
    union {
        T value = {};
    };
```

или

```
    constexpr Optional() : value{}, has_value_{false} { }
```

Кстати, зачем здесь union?

Comment: "Кстати, зачем здесь union?" - чтобы ничего не хранить, когда значения нет. А почему в C++20 работает?

Comment: Так он всегда хранится (память тратится). Хотите сэкономить на вызове конструктора (который для int - тривиальны)? Или хотите работать с типами, у которых нет конструктора по умолчанию? Используйте placement new/delete и буфер из char-ов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52338325

Comment: @curui, вы все путаете (смысл объединения, константного выражения ...).   Это следствие не внимательного изучения того, что читаете и пишете.